# How to resolve the following “keyserver receive failed” issue on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS while installing MongoDB?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, mongodb

[image: Keyserver not available error.]

I am trying to install MongoDB on my system. I try to follow the steps given in the following website - [Click Here](https://hevodata.com/blog/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

I am getting the 'keyserver not available' error as given in the image above due to which I am not able to install MongoDB on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please format your post in a proper way - use plain text instead of images!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an older versions of the instructions. For the latest you should check out the [official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). As of writing this answer that line looks like this:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4
```

If you still fail with a similar error then the issue is that your host/vm can't resolve/reach the `keyserver.ubuntu.com` address and you essentially have to troubleshoot your connection to that server.